# margin top responsive using clip-path and bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, clip-path

I would like to know, if there is any possibility that i can keep margin:top responsive for all scenarios, i.e. different devices or if i re-size browser using mouse?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="main container">
  <div class="col-md-12 left-border">
    <div class="col-md-12 left">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12 left-Triangle-border float-left trinagle-left-position">
    <div class=" col-md-12 left-Triangle">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.main{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: black;
}
.float-left{float:left;}

.trinagle-left-position{margin-top: -56px;}

.left {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #1e90ff;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(2% 2%, 99% 2%, 99% 99%, 2% 62%);
clip-path: polygon(2% 2%, 99% 2%, 99% 99%, 2% 62%);
}
.left:hover{
   opacity:0.5;
}
.left-border {
    width: 99%;
    height: 49%;
  float: left;
    background: black;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 62%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 62%);
}

.left-Triangle-border {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: black;
    -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 97% 27%);
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 0% 100%, 97% 27%);
}
.left-Triangle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    background: #1e90ff;;
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(1% 1%, 0 99%, 95% 27%);
clip-path: polygon(1% 1%, 0 99%, 95% 27%);
}
.left-Triangle:hover{
   opacity:0.5;
}

html, body { height: 100%; }
body {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Here is my [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqdasiftekhar/dk2ap168/21/). What i want here is, mentioned below in image.

These are two shapes which i am trying developing using css clip-path polygon. but when i give margin top to  div which is filled with green color and i re-size browser window it is not contain its position.

One solution which i found is using media queries and changing margin top based on media queries. but in case of re-sizing browser, it do not works.

any thoughts on this if i can make margin top responsive using bootstrap?

Comment: U can give margin-top in ***%***, but note that it will take it's height against width of it's parent div, and not height. plus it will always maintain aspect ratio of the div if u have width in percents as well and not pixels.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i tried in percent but on re-sizing browser it creates big difference (gap).

Comment: where exactly do u want ur responsive margin to be ? I cant see any green shapes in your fiddle

Comment: difference between triangle and above shape. u can say difference between div with class left-border and div with left-Triangle-border

Comment: it's parent div has fixed width and height, in that case margin-top cant be responsive in order to make it responsive u should have responsive parent div as well